# Same behavior apply to different elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

For `div.spot1` and `div.spot2` I want the same behaviors - hide delete button when image input is empty, show delete btn when image is uploaded, change image src when image is uploaded, click delete btn to send ajax request to server etc. Of course I can copy/paste js code of spot1 to spot2, only changing the class from `first` to `second`. But say I have 4 spots like this, then I will have four almost identical code in my js file. I fear that's not the best practice. What should I do?

HTML:

```
    <form class='upload' action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="spot1">
            <span class='filename first'>FILE 1</span>
            <button type='button' class='delete first'>&#x274C</button>
            <input type="file" name="image" class="input first" accept="image/*">
            <input type="button" value="+" class="browse first"/> 
            <a href="{{ourl}}" class="fancybox" title="{{title}}"><img class="tn first" src="{{turl}}"></a>
            <span class="status first"></span>
        </div>

        <div class="spot2">
            <span class='filename second'>FILE 1</span>
            <button type='button' class='delete second'>&#x274C</button>
            <input type="file" name="image" class="input second" accept="image/*">
            <input class="browse second" type="button" value="+"/> 
            <a href="{{ourl}}" class="fancybox" title="{{title}}"><img class="tn second" src="{{turl}}"></a>
            <span class="status second"></span>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Part of the JS (just for making an example):

```js
if ( $('.tn.first').attr('src') == "") {
    ...
}

$('.browse.first').on("click", function () {
    $('.input.first').click();
 });

$('.input.first').on('change', function () {
...
};
```

Comment: if you have multiple elements of the same type, that represent the same type of data and/or functionality, it's probably a good idea to give them the same class name.

Comment: I'm agree with basilikum, why the divs have not the same class name if these have the same behavior.

Comment: @Philip007 I didn't realize, i already posted a comment since I decided to make an answer out of it. But anyway, the trick is to select the `span` that has the same parent as the image. jQuery provides you with a lot of useful functions that let you do exactly that and many more ([link](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/)): `$(".tn").first().parent().find(".status")`

Answer (score 0):

That is indeed not best practice.

If you know what kind of structure you will have (exactly), you can do something like this:

```
var FileModule = function(elem) {
    // Throw your events here
}
```

Instantiating it is as simple as passing your elements in it. If you are using jQuery, you can do this exactly using the `$.fn.extend()` function, as follows:

```
$.fn.FileModule = function() {
  return this.each(function() {
   // `this` is your element
   $(this).find(".input.first").on("change", function() { ... });
  });
};
```

From there, you can initialize your **module** (that is what it is) by calling `FileModule` on a jQuery selector that contains your spots.

If you want even more dynamic, consider binding custom events on it in order to allow external portions of your code to interact with it. This is beyond the scope of your question, hozever.

Answer (score 0):

How about change markup following way

```html
<form class='upload' action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="spot" id="spot1">
        <span class='filename'>FILE 1</span>
        <button type='button' class='delete'>&#x274C</button>
        <input type="file" name="image" class="input" accept="image/*">
        <input type="button" value="+" class="browse"/> 
        <a href="{{ourl}}" class="fancybox" title="{{title}}"><img class="tn" src="{{turl}}"></a>
        <span class="status"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="spot" id="spot2">
        <span class='filename'>FILE 2</span>
        <button type='button' class='delete'>&#x274C</button>
        <input type="file" name="image" class="input" accept="image/*">
        <input class="browse" type="button" value="+"/> 
        <a href="{{ourl}}" class="fancybox" title="{{title}}"><img class="tn" src="{{turl}}"></a>
        <span class="status"></span>
    </div>
</form>
```

And JS

```js
$('.spot .browse').on('click', function () {
    $(this).parent().find('.input').click();
 });

$('.spot .input').on('change', function () {
   alert('I\'m input of type file of ' + $(this).parent().prop('id') + ' and I\'m changed');
});
```

Here is **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7UfPm/)** demo

Comment: Should there be a space in the middle of `$('.spot.browse')`? It supposed to be a descendent selector right?

Comment: @Philip007 Exactly. Thanks. That was a typo.

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple elements of the same type, that represent the same type of data and/or functionality, they should have the same class name. You can add additional attributes to your elements that tell you which one of that class it is, like this:

```
<div class="spot" index="1">
    <span class='filename'>FILE 1</span>
    <button type='button' class='delete'>&#x274C</button>
    <input type="file" name="image" class="input" accept="image/*">
    <input type="button" value="+" class="browse"/> 
    <a href="{{ourl}}" class="fancybox" title="{{title}}"><img class="tn" src="{{turl}}"></a>
    <span class="status"></span>
</div>
```

This lets you now write:

```
$('.browse').on("click", function () {
    $(this).find('.input').click();
 });
```

Comment: say that we have two title span. I want to check if a title span is empty. How can I give them the same class names? Lets say title1 is empty while title2 is not. How should I code this if statement?

Comment: @Philip007 for that specific purpose you could use `.each()`: `$(".title").each(function(index){ if ($(this).text() === "") { /*do something*/ } })`

Answer (score -1):

Since you're already using jquery there is a selector which selects based on a substring within in an attribute (attribute contains).

```
$('div[class*="spot"]').doSomething();
```

Comment: This misses the point. His selectors are bound globally, which means that your code sidesteps that issue. Furthermore, the class*= CSS filter is incredibly inefficient, especially if it has to loop through every div on the page.